# Marshal.SizeOf(strurtureType) Always throws error

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke

Following is my code snippet

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program.GetState(new State() { enabled = true, currentLimit = 30 });
    }

    private static void GetState(State result)
    {
        IntPtr Ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(result));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(result, Ptr, false);
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct State
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I8)]
    public uint currentLimit;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool enabled;
}
```

It always throws an error i.e.

> *Type 'MarshellingStructureSize.State' cannot be marshaled as an
>   unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed*.

My intention is to send a structure for a native DLL through pInvoke but when I try to allocate memory for my structure in Managed code through Marshal it always throw above error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since, it's partially related to pinvoking native dlls therefore useful points can come from C++ community as well.

Comment: The problem is the MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I8) for currentLimit. A uint in C# has only a size of 4 bytes. Change the attribute to UnmangedType.U4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uint` is actually alias for `System.UInt32` which occupies 4 bytes in memory. I think `currentLimit` can't be converted to 8 bytes in memory, that is why you get an error.

```
[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I8)]
public uint currentLimit;
```

`I8` is for signed 8 byte integer. try changing it to `U4` or `I4`.

```
[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U4)]
public uint currentLimit;
```

Or change type of `currentLimit` to `ulong` as @Hans Passant suggested.

```
[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I8)] //or U8 
public ulong currentLimit;
```

this works.

Comment: Right, or make it ulong.

Comment: @HansPassant Of course, that depends upon OP's need. :) I'll update in my answer thanks